# Using MySQL with group_concat variables to create a new row

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'd like to select some values from a MySQL table like below. I want to concat the tactical and ID variables only when the koords values match. The output of the query should have all rows in the table, replacing the duplicates with just one row. 
In short I want to combine two rows into one if the two match on there latitude and longitude values. And concatenate several of the values into columns.
Is this possible?

Original table columns are: ID, netID, tactical, Name, latitude, longitude.

```
SELECT ID, tactical
            ,CONCAT(latitude, ", ", longitude) as koords
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(tactical SEPARATOR '-')  as newtact
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR '-') as newID
FROM `NetLog` 
WHERE netID = 276
```

The goal is to create a marker in Google Maps that contains the information for the duplicate records. The mapping part is done, I just need to combine duplicates at this point.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `group by`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(latitude, ', ', longitude) as koords,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tactical SEPARATOR '-')  as newtact,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR '-') as newID
FROM `NetLog` 
WHERE netID = 276
GROUP BY latitude, longitude;
```

Why the designers of MySQL would let a query such as yours run with no error is beyond me.  It is not standard SQL, because you have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` along with aggregation functions.

Comment: Well I can't comment on your concern but I can say I think you answered my question. I tried all kinds of things and yet it was in the end a very simple solution I'm sorry I didn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser . . . You might have found it much sooner if you got an error saying that `latitude` is not in a `group by` and not aggregated.